# Input text form value from HTML into Javascript function

Tags: javascript, function, textbox

Beginner question, I am currently learning JS and I'm trying to write a function that will take a text input from a simple html form. I can't figure out how to pass the text input into the function. This is what I am currently trying:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script type = "text/javascript">
        <!--

        var myColor = document.getElementById("textbox").value;


        function findColor(){
        switch(myColor){
            case "Blue":
                document.write("just like the sky!");
            break

            case "Red":
                document.write("Just like wine!");
            break
            default:
                document.write("Suit yourself then...");

            }
        }

        //-->
        </script>

        <form>
        Colour <input type="text" name="inputform" id="textbox" value="">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="findColor();">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks, any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put this line:

```
 var myColor = document.getElementById("textbox").value;
```

Inside the `findColor` function:

```
function findColor(){
    var myColor = document.getElementById("textbox").value;
    switch(myColor){ //...
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm with David's answer. You are using a form  and you need to prevent default submission event like below by pasing a event parameter to the function as shown in the below code.

```
function findColor(e){ // e is a event parameter passed
        e.preventDefault();
        var myColor = document.getElementById("textbox").value;
        switch(myColor){
            case "Blue":
                document.write("just like the sky!");
            break

            case "Red":
                document.write("Just like wine!");
            break
            default:
                document.write("Suit yourself then...");

            }
            return false;
}
```

and in html,

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="findColor(event);">
```

As you can see I'm passing event like this  `findColor(event)` in html

And a suggestion :

read about the `document.write` [here](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/) and see a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/addyosmani/6T9vX/) here the author explained it very neatly as

> The use of document.write where native DOM alternatives such as
>   document.createElement are more appropriate. document.write has been
>   grossly misused over the years and has quite a few disadvantages
>   including that if it's executed after the page has been loaded it can
>   actually overwrite the page we're on, whilst document.createElement
>   does not. We can see here for a live example of this in action. It
>   also doesn't work with XHTML which is another reason opting for more
>   DOM-friendly methods such as document.createElement is favorable.

Answer (score 0):

Or to pass it to the function do this:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="findColor('Blue');">

 function findColor(myColor){
        switch(myColor){
            case "Blue":
                document.write("just like the sky!");
            break

            case "Red":
                document.write("Just like wine!");
            break
            default:
                document.write("Suit yourself then...");

            }
        }
```

Comment: that could work but defining onclick handlers inline is not a recommend practice

Comment: This would work, its an example of how to pass something to a function, which was the question. Its an alternative to the other answers with the intention of helping a JavaScript beginner.

Comment: not trying to ruffle your feathers :) I changed it from would to could work as I wasnt sure about hardcoding the onclick value. If I was going to post this sample I would do it as `onclick="findColor(document.getElementById('textbox').value);"` so it worked based on the input. But also I wouldn't use onclick at all . But also I would use jquery so that will probably upset people anyway haha

Comment: No worries, your way is better, and Andrews is even better, it was just a simply example of how to pass data to a function. Jquery is deffo better

Answer (score 0):

when the browser reads your html page it interprets the javascript section thus defining your findColor function and  executing the line

```
var myColor = document.getElementById("textbox").value;
```

Therefor myColor receives the initial value of your textbox element. By the time the page is fully loaded and you enter a value in the textbox the myColor assignment is already done. To make sure that the assignment is done at the right time, after clicking submit, aka when the findColor functiom is called, you have the two options mentioned above: Make the assignemt the first statement in your findColor function OR make it a parameter to the findColor function

There is a second flaw in this example. A form's submit triggers reloading of an HTML page. Therefore you never see the result of your findColor function. A better way to play with Javascript is to tie functions to buttons.  See the revised html below.

I trust you have seen the w3school JavaScript tutorials http://www.w3schools.com/js/.  Have a look at http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script type = "text/javascript">
        function findColor(myColor){
        output = document.getElementById('output'); 
        switch(myColor){
            case "Blue":
                output.innerHTML = "Just like the sky"; 
                break
            case "Red":
                output.innerHTML = "Just like the wine"; 
                break
            default:
                output.innerHTML ="Suit yourself then...";
            }
        }
        </script>

        <form>
        Colour <input type="text" name="inputform" id="textbox" value="">
        </form> 

        <button type="button" onclick="findColor(document.getElementById('textbox').value);"> FindColor </button>
        </form>

        <div id="output"> what I think of this color </div>
    </body>
</html>
```